# Toggling a class within another component

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject, common-data-service

my understanding of Angular is very basic (I'm trying to learn!) and need some help with regards to setting a click event between 2 separate components. I'll specify the scenario...

**I have a header menu which contains a button which on click, will expand and collapse a side menu. The header menu and side menu are separate components. I need to basically toggle a class inside the sidebar component when the button in the header component is clicked**

I've read that it might be best to create a service (rxjs/BehaviorSubject) that links the two components together however I've never created one before so not really sure how to proceed.

Is anyone able to assist? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to create one Subject which stores your className/ variable , 
On click of button , you have to change the value of Subject ,
In the menu Component, you have to subscribe the value of subject in the ngOnOnit function 
Based on the variable value you can toggle the class.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem. Service+RxJS is a very elegant solution, yet perhaps a bit much for a beginner. Start simple. Create a service, and have it injected in both components. Give that service a public property, which holds the current CSS class. In the header menu, update the Service's property. Use the property directly in your side menu's template. I believe that should work. Progress to RxJS and Subjects from there. To create the service, you can use the CLI (ng c service <service name> I believe)

Answer (score 3):

As per Software Engineering prospective, identify the problem first, then think of the solution within the scope of design patterns, but also take in consideration the framework. In the mentioned scenario; the **Observer Pattern** is what you are looking for.

We need to communicate between components that might or might not be located within the same `module` which also might have a parent-child or child-parent relationship, or might be brothers-relationship or might not have a relationship at all! So the generic solution is to created a `Service`.

Now according to your use case, you're calling it as if you have this one only functionality in which you want to **observe** this button to **toggle** the sidenav, but from my own point of view, it's better to create a more generic form of usage in which is defined as **"Communication"**. This will make your service reusable and can do many other things than just observing a button.

I'll add some code to demonstrate.

First of all we've got the `communication.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root', // Singleton
})
export class ComunicationService {
  private subject: Subject<any>;
  private observable$: Observable<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.subject = new Subject();
    this.observable$ = this.subject.asObservable();
  }

  sendData(data: any) {
    this.subject.next(data);
  }

  clearData() {
    this.subject.next();
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.observable$;
  }
}
```

Now in the `header.component.ts` for example we need to use `DI` design pattern to inject this service and use it to `sendData`.

```
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(private communicationService: CommunicationService) {}

  onButtonClick() {
    this.communicationService.sendData(ANYTHING_YOU_WANT_TO_SHARE);
  }
}
```

And in your `sidenav.component.ts`

```
export class SidenavComponent {
  constructor(private comunicationService: CommunicationService) {
    this.listenToButtonClicks(); // Never forget to call the subscribing function in the constructor, and unsubscribe OnDestroy to prevent memory leak
  }

  listenToButtonClicks() {
    this.communicationService.getData().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res); // Check if you're getting the data
      // Do whatever you need to do here with the shared data
      this.toggleSidenave(); // Call the function that toggles the Sidenav
    })
  }
}
```

And we're done!

Now what makes `BehaviorSubject` special is that it can be initialized with an initial value (*To indicate that sidenav is closed by default for example*).

You can learn more about `BehaviorSubject` [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject)

Hope this helped & Happy coding!